# SQL behavior in a query

Tags: sql, database

I created a very easy SQL statement to get a specific row in the database, but first I didn't get any data, although I knew that the data is in the database.

So I tried it again in a different way and I found the entry, but now I would like to know, what's the different between those statements (see screenshot).

**Edit**: the `PolNrKorin` value in the statement is not the same as in the result, because I changed it before I uploaded it here (data protection)

Here is the code:

```
declare @searchParam nvarchar(8) 
set @searchParam = '04521865'

declare @searchParam2 int 
set @searchParam = 04521865

select 
    QuittungGuid, AngebotGuid, QuittungID, AntragsNr, PolNrKorin, Datum 
from 
    Quittung 
where 
    PolNrKorin = 04521865

select 
    QuittungGuid, AngebotGuid, QuittungID, AntragsNr, PolNrKorin, Datum 
from 
    Quittung 
where 
    PolNrKorin = '04521865'

select  
    QuittungGuid, AngebotGuid, QuittungID, AntragsNr, PolNrKorin, Datum 
from 
    Quittung 
where 
    PolNrKorin = @searchParam 

select  
    QuittungGuid, AngebotGuid, QuittungID, AntragsNr, PolNrKorin, Datum 
from 
    Quittung 
where 
    PolNrKorin = @searchParam2
```

[image: sql statement]

Comment: please post the actual code in the question, not a screenshot of the code

Comment: You gave a value both times to the same variable. And also the value you gave to your variable isn't the same value you are getting in the results, so please post the right code and results

Comment: @Lamak is right, you're setting an `int` value to a `nvarchar(8)` parameter. Check the declaration of `@searchParam2`

Comment: yes I know.. but why does it work if I don't use the params? whats the diffrent is between  PolNrKorin = '04521865' and PolNrKorin = @searchParam ?

Comment: @D.Nehl but how can we know it actually works?, maybe it isn't working and you are not comparing the right code with the results. You said you changed for data protection, but the big black rectangles should do the work just fine, no need to change results

Comment: @Lamak I only changed the number in the statement, because this is the policy number and I cannot show you the right number...

Answer (score 0):

It could be the second declaration, @searchParam2 should be set. @searchParam appears to be set twice.

Answer (score -1):

The single quotes around the ID you’re specifying in the WHERE clause are forcing the search to execute against the ID as text, rather than as an Integer. If the data is stored in the table as a TEXT representation of a numeric value, then you will need to use single quotes around the field to filter on it in the WHERE clause.

Comment: The 2 firsts `SELECT` are working. This isn't the issue. (Not my downvote by the way)

Comment: @Cid the 2 firsts `SELECT`s aren't actually working though. In the screenshot posted, the values for the column `PolNrKorin` aren't the same as the ones used in the code.